# How can I improve performance of producing String for output in Haskell

Tags: performance, haskell

I have a program that I am trying to make faster, mostly for the sake of making it faster to learn more about Haskell.  For comparison I have written the same program in C and have a 4x speed improvement.  I expected faster from C, but that kind of difference makes me think I have something wrong.

So I have profiled the Haskell code and over 50% of the time is spent producing the formatted `String` for output. So just this section takes more than my entire C program.  The function is similar to this:

```
display :: POSIXTime -> [(Int, Centi)] -> IO()
display t l = putStrLn $ t_str ++ " " ++ l_str
    where
        t_str = show . timeToTimeOfDay . unsafeCoerce $ (t `mod` posixDayLength)
        l_str = intercalate " " $ map displayPair l
        displayPair (a,b) = show a ++ " " ++ show b
```

Notes about the code:
The `unsafeCoerce` is to convert `NominalDiffTime` to `DiffTime` which have the same type but this is faster than `toRational . fromRational` which I had been using.

`Centi` is defined in `Data.Fixed` and is a number with 2 decimal places

`TimeOfDay` is as you would expect just hours, minutes and seconds (stored with picosecond accuracy).

`` `mod` posixDayLength `` is so we just get the time of day ignoring which day it is (because that is all I care about ... it is from a timestamp and I know that it had to be today - I just care what time today!).

I have tried using `ShowS (String -> String)` to concatenate results and this is not significantly faster.

I have tried using `Data.Text` but that makes the code slower (presumably spends too much time packing strings).

I used to have the `putStrLn` in a separate function but it is faster here (less thunks built up? but why?).

Is there an easy way to improve output performance in Haskell that I'm missing?

Comment: `type String = [Char]` is not suitable (nor intended) for anything where performance matters. (`Data.ByteString` and `Data.Text` are.) But _does it matter_? This is likely bounded by IO performance, I reckon the C version has almost none of its execution time in the program itself.

Comment: Try using `Text` instead of `String`! Linked lists are not meant for performance.

Comment: but the type of putStrLn is :: String -> IO. So how do I avoid String in IO?

Comment: @dave Use [Data.Text.IO](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.1.1.2/docs/Data-Text-IO.html)

Comment: I should clarify, since the putStrLn was previously in a different function it isn't the IO per se that is slow but the building of the String that I wish to output.  So saying "bounded by IO performance" is not true, it is bounded by the processing required to get the string for the IO.

Comment: I'd be willing to give you a hand if you post complete code that compiles and uses either `criterion` or `TimeIt`.

Comment: After changing `String` to `Text`, the next biggest slowdown is probably the `time` library.  You can try thyme, http://hackage.haskell.org/package/thyme, which is a drop-in replacement.

Comment: I am _really_ missing how changing to Text would help.  My change is to add Text.pack after I have created the String. But the source of slowness is creating the string, not the output of said String. So it does nothing to improve performance. And I can't see where I can manipulate a Text type to build one directly from my types.  What am I missing?

Comment: A number of your constructs are slow.  For example, you use `++` a lot - using Text's `append` would be much faster.

Comment: `Text.append` might be faster than `++`, but this doesn't increase the speed of the overall function as calling `Text.pack` before all the strings is even slower.

Comment: Did you actually benchmark the code to make that determination?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: yes.

Comment: If you stop using String here at all and use Text entirely (OverloadedStrings extension will help), you won't have that problem. Also Text (and ByteString) provides a `Builder` module for efficient concatenation-based construction of Text values, which might be useful here as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For producing output the highest performance can be found by avoiding String in favour of either a ByteString or Text.  In order to build the output there is a special data type called `Builder`.  There is a good description with examples in the [ByteString] hackage description.

The resulting code looks like this:

```
import Data.Monoid
display :: POSIXTime -> [(Int, Centi)] -> IO()
display t l = hPutBuilder stdout $ t_str <> space <> l_str
    where
        space = (byteString . pack) " "
        t_str = (byteString . pack . show . timeToTimeOfDay . unsafeCoerce) $ (t `mod` posixDayLength)
        l_str = foldr <> space $ map displayPair l
        displayPair (a,b) = intDec a <> space <> (byteString . pack . show) b
```

The builder data type builds up chunks that it will then concatenate in O(1) in to a buffer for the output.  Unfortunately, not all types have a builder for them and only the base types.  So for outputting the others the only solution is to pack the string ... or perhaps to write a function to create a builder (and add it to the library?).

Comment: You can use the `OverloadedStrings` extension to avoid constructing (and then immediately throwing away) any string literals. You can use Data.Text.Builder to write builders instead of using `show` to display values (this is its intended use, after all). I don't think the unsafeCoerce is necessary at all and I would recommend avoiding it.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs: see the question as to why it exists: it is necessary to convert from `NominalDiffTime` to `DiffTime` both of which have the same representation and is faster than the alternative `(fromRational . toRational)`